# How to strip certain tags within a div using RegEx

Tags: html, regex

I have some extremely messy HTML, with several `<span>` tags I'd like to get rid off. Some of the are closed, others aren't. Sometimes there are randon line-breaks in the markup. As I said, messy.

Example:

```
<div class="post">
<span style="color: #007700">!</span>
<span style="color: #0000BB">defineLOW1</span>
<span style="color: #007700">$</span><span style="color: #0000BB">0
<br /></span><span style="color: #007700">!</span>
<span style="color: #0000BB">deinfeHIGH1</span><span style="color: #007700">$</span>
<span style="color: #0000BB">1
<br /></span>
<span style="color: #007700">!</span>
<span style="color: #0000BB">defineLOW2</span><span style="color: #007700">$</span><span style="color: #0000BB">2
<br /></span>
<span style="color: #007700">!</span>
<span style="color: #0000BB">deinfeHIGH2</span><span style="color: #007700">$</span><span style="color: #0000BB">3
</div>
```

What I'm looking for is a way to strip all `<span>` and `</span>`tags within the div of the class `post`, as I'd like to run a script over a bunch of static HTML pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people are quick to point out, [regular expressions cannot completely parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).  That doesn't mean you can't do useful manipulations of HTML with regex.  In your case, in particular, because you have malformed HTML, and your task is pretty straightforward, you'll be able to accomplish what you want with regular expressions.  There could be some edge cases, though, so I would encourage you to run your HTML through an HTML validator when you're done to *really* clean things up.

One thing that could cause a lot of problems is if you have nested `<div>` elements.  (We're not going to worry about nested `<span>` elements, because we're just going to remove them all.)  It's a general problem with regular expressions.  If you use this match:

```
<div class="post">[^]*</div>
```

Note: the `[^]` is an *empty negated character class*, designed to match everything, *including* newlines.  The dot metacharacter, by contrast, doesn't match newlines, which is why we're not using it.  This may not work in all regular expression implementations, as Bohemian points out in the comments below.  I know it works in .NET and JavaScript.  If it doesn't work in your implementation, you can use the clunkier `(?:.|\n)` or `[\s\S]`.

That will work fine until you have this HTML:

```
<div class="post">
    <span>Some text in a span.</span>
    <div>
      <span>Some more text in a span.</span>
    </div>
    <span>Whoops!  I'll get missed....</span>
</div>
```

That last `<span>` won't be included in your match because it will match the opening div, then the FIRST closing `</div>` tag it comes to...which is actually part of an inner div.

So, if you have that going on, you have a much more complicated problem, and you'll have to implement something a little more sophisticated (like a real HTML parser, which is going to have complications because your HTML is ill-formed).

Moving on, let's assume that you don't have additional `<div>`s nested inside the `<div class="post">`.  Your first regex is going to be to match that whole div:

```
<div .*\bclass="post".*>(.*)</div>
```

That'll get all the divs you want.  I don't know what language or flavor of regular expressions you're using, but most support some kind of nested replacement.  What you'll want to do is do a **second** replacement on the first matched group (what's inside the div).  That one will be pretty simple.  Just replace `<span\b.*?>` with a single space or `&nbsp;`.  I recommend replacing with some whitespace because otherwise you might run into some problems with spans butted up to each other.  That will kind of be up to you.

Some notes:

- I've written all of these as case sensitive.  If you have `<SPAN>` or `class="Post"` or the like, you'll have to make it case inensitive.
- I haven't taken into account additional whitespace.  So this won't match `<div class = "post">`.  This is easy enough to fix if that's an issue.
- I haven't taken into account the use of single quotes.  So this won't match `<div class='post'>`.  Again, this is pretty easy to fix.

If you're using regexes in an editor, this will be a little trickier because no editor I know of allows you to do sub-replacements.  However, in most programming languages, this will be possible.  If you let me know what you're using to execute your regular expressions, I can make this answer more complete.

Comment: `[^]` is invalid: it produces the error "empty character class".

Comment: Not correct, Bohemian.  `[^]` is an empty *negated* character class.  That includes everything.  You might think that's the same as `.`, but you'd be wrong: `.` matches everything EXCEPT newlines.  `[^]` matches everything INCLUDING newlines.  So it's kind of like a "super period".

Comment: In the OPs case, I assumed there would be line breaks in his input, and he would want to match over them, so `.` would not be sufficient, hence the `[^]`.

Comment: I know this works in .NET and JavaScript regular expressions; not sure about other implementations.  If it doesn't work in your regular expression implementation, you can use the clunkier `(?:.|\n)` instead.

Comment: Sorry to contradict you, Bohemian: it appears that the empty negated character class does not work in all regular expression implementations.  I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I know exactly what it's for, but it doesn't work in ruby or java (haven't tested others). The universal approach is both sides of an inclusive and exclusive group eg `[\s\S]`.

Comment: Hm, I like that approach, Bohemian (`[\s\S]`).  I'll tuck that one away in my bag of tricks, thanks for bringing that to my attention.  I still find `[^]` to be the most appealing, but I was not aware it did not work in other implementations.  Thanks for educating me!

Comment: It's what I get for being arrogant and quick to correct people!

Comment: I wish it *did* work everywhere. It *looks* really elegant. The reason for my bringing it up was that the language context has not been indicated in the question either by tags or by mention, so we can only guess.

Comment: Yup, you were right to bring it up!  Thanks again, and happy coding.

Comment: Thank you for this super-thorough answer, I really appreciate your effort. As this was a one-off conversion, I've only been trying to solve this with a text-editor only (Sublime Text), but it seems I might be better off using a script.